# Is the EclipseLink EntityManagerFactory thread safe?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

Is the EclipseLink EntityManagerFactory thread safe?

Is it safe to entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager() in the multi-threaded environment to obtain a EntityManager per method call?

Thanks

Comment: Only you need to worry about thread safe EMF not EM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation of EclipseLink `EntityManagerFactory` :

```
org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl
```

uses the delegate ...

```
org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate
```

and none of the `EntityManagerFactoryDelegate` APIs are thread safe. So, the EntityManagerFactory API is not thread safe.

Comment: The EntityManagerFactory though doesn't do much; it is just a factory for EntityManager instances, and the EclipseLink factory code has synchronized where it initializes shared sessions.  It should be thread safe as long as you aren't closing it out from under a thread still using it.  But EclipseLink's factory is just a wrapper, so creating new Factories to be safe isn't expensive and can avoid problems overall.

Answer (score 0):

Methods of the EntityManagerFactory interface are threadsafe.

And you can create EntityManager for each method-call/request for a particular unit of work. EntityManager instances are'n thread safe.